# Splitting a string using '|'

Tags: java, regex, salesforce, apex-code

I have a string

```
&#124;      859706 &#124; Conficker infected host at 192.168.155.60    &#124;        5744 &#124;       7089 &#124;        5 &#124;                 4 &#124; 1309714576 &#124;
                1 &#124; completed           &#124;
```

I need to split the using | which is nothing but pipe ( | ) symbol
when i give the following split i get size of the array as 0

```
columns=parts[i].split('&#124;');
```

where parts and columns  are  string arrays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` is a regex special character - you can escape it with backslash, so in java, you would write

```
columns=parts[i].split("\\|"); //first backslash escapes the second for java
```

**EDIT:** and if you need to support trailing empty columns, don't forget to use

```
columns=parts[i].split("\\|", -1);
```

Comment: that `-1` options i was looking for +1 for it

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue and it worked with an escape char in the front
i.e.

```
parts[i].split("\\|")
```

Answer (score 0):

In split method use "[|]" instead "|".

Answer (score 0):

you can try `columns=parts[i].split("|");`